# material ui align inline FormLabel and RadioGroup

Tags: css, flexbox, material-ui

im strugling looking a workaround to get a formlabel (plus a tooltip) align in the same row with the radio group, im using this exact same example from the documentation:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/rowradiobuttonsgroup-material-demo-forked-v155b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

but im trying to achive this:
[image: achive this]

If anyone has an idea how can i work on this, would be great, i tried passing with sx props a flex-direction row display inline, but nothing

this its the code i trying to pass to the formlabel:

```
<FormLabel 
    component="legend"
    sx={{  
      marginBottom:{ sm:'4px' },
      textAlign: { sm:'left'},
      clear: { sm:'both'},
      float: {sm: 'left'},
      marginRight: { sm:'20px'},
      marginLeft: {sm:'10px'},}}
    >
```

Comment: What's the example documentation you followed?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/2l1g3?file=/demo.js this

Comment: Can you share your code what you tried?

Comment: already edit the original post with the code i tried, and it works if i setted manually in chrome, but im cant pass it

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, with the code passed to the FormLabel, i passed to the parent Formcontrol tag, flex-direction row, and thats it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).